# Sum of replicated matrices

Tags: code-golf, math, array, matrix

Given a list of numbers \$[a_1, a_2, ... a_n]\$, compute the sum of all the matrices \$A_i\$ where \$A_i\$ is defined as follows (\$m\$ is the maximum of all \$a_i\$):

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
       & 1 & 2 & \cdots & i-1 &  i  & i+1 & \cdots &  n  \\
\hline
1      & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0  & a_i & a_i & \cdots & a_i \\
2      & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0  & a_i & a_i & \cdots & a_i \\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_i    & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0  & a_i & a_i & \cdots & a_i \\
a_{i+1}& 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0  &  0  &  0  & \cdots &  0  \\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
m      & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0  &  0  &  0  & \cdots &  0  \\
\end{array}
$$

### Example

Given the input `[2,1,3,1]` we construct the following matrix:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 3 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

### Rules and I/O

- you may assume the input is non-empty
- you may assume all the inputs are non-negative (0≤)
- the input can be a \$1×n\$ (or \$n×1\$) matrix, list, array etc.
- similarly the output can be a matrix, list of lists, array etc.
- you can take and return inputs via any [default I/O format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- your submission may be a full program or function

### Test cases

```
[0] -> [] or [[]]
[1] -> [[1]]
[3] -> [[3],[3],[3]]
[2,2] -> [[2,4],[2,4]]
[3,0,0] -> [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]
[1,2,3,4,5] -> [[1,3,6,10,15],[0,2,5,9,14],[0,0,3,7,12],[0,0,0,4,9],[0,0,0,0,5]]
[10,1,0,3,7,8] -> [[10,11,11,14,21,29],[10,10,10,13,20,28],[10,10,10,13,20,28],[10,10,10,10,17,25],[10,10,10,10,17,25],[10,10,10,10,17,25],[10,10,10,10,17,25],[10,10,10,10,10,18],[10,10,10,10,10,10],[10,10,10,10,10,10]]
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's a font difference or something.  I see you rolled back my edit.  This is how it currently looks to me https://imgur.com/a06RH9r  This is Chrome on Windows 10.  The vertical ellipses are not rendered in monospace for some reason, and don't align with the columns.  That's why I changed it.  But I guess it must look different in different environments.

Comment: Definitely a font issue. Both revisions are misaligned on my screen.

Comment: May we return the result transposed?

Comment: [we need mathjax!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14910/17360)

Comment: @Adám: I'm gonna say no to that, however feel free to include a solution in your post that does so.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 5 bytes

```
ẋ"z0Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrm6lKoPDLf8Ptz9qWuMOxFmPGvcd2nZo2///0UY6hjrGOoaxOgrRBiACzDIGEUY6RmC2joEOREbHCKjSRMcUzDEA6jMA8s11LGIB)

#### How it works

```
ẋ"z0Ä  Main link. Argument: A (array)


       e.g. [2, 1, 3, 1]

ẋ"     Repeat each n in A n times.

       e.g. [[2, 2   ]
             [1      ]
             [3, 3, 3]
             [1      ]]

  z0   Zipfill 0; read the result by columns, filling missing elements with 0's.

        e.g. [[2, 1, 3, 1]
              [2, 0, 3, 0]
              [0, 0, 3, 0]]

    Ä  Take the cumulative sum of each row vector.

       e.g. [[2, 3, 6, 7]
             [2, 2, 5, 5]
             [0, 0, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
n=sum((a=scan())|1);for(i in 1:n)F=F+`[<-`(matrix(0,max(a),n),0:a[i],i:n,a[i]);F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxCoAwDADAr2RMMEKrW7VrPyGCQRAyNEJV6ODfK950pTWL15MRJV67GBK9nqbjLKigBj4YpZi6bZn7DbPcRSs6zlJRiI3YBVl0ZQ3Gf2hKbQAPI/j2AQ)

Takes input from stdin; prints a `0x1` matrix for input `0`, which prints out like

```r
	[,1]
```

Comment: For those wondering, `F` is a built-in global variable whose initial value is `FALSE`. Here it's coerced to 0 and used as the initial value of the cumulative sum. This answer demonstrates the reason not to use `F` and `T` except in code specifically designed never to be actually used!

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>70</s> <s>66</s> 51 bytes

```hs
g x=[scanl1(+)[sum[n|n>=r]|n<-x]|r<-[1..maximum x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY3BasMwDIbvfgoddtiYXCwnWVNo@gZ7AqODGaMLjb2SrBBY9uyZnDqDQWGXgWzp//RLevPD6bXr5vkIY@OGFx87un98cMMluDjFQ9PzFPd65Knfa0ebTfBjGy4BRuY5@DZCA8Gfn@Hct/ED7uAIziJhgcRKfWrlDIM@gGN478E5ZuXoSiSLKLIoGPMTaNFmbLEUmP7kRYNm9cuJxf8rp@1opSyxWq@IekIySJXYjHQr3CGVizDS3CLZLIzM7X5qIzvSQhnNxnrdKYiWKNHKwTST2DUKtHKm/pNJbNFW/8kk6hvM3GSs9Nf8DQ)

Comment: As a puzzle, there is a 54 byte version ;)

Comment: @BMO How about 51 bytes instead?

Comment: Very nice! Mine was [this](https://tio.run/##rY/BasMwDIbvfgodeliZXGwnWdPR9g36BEIHE0YXFmcl6SCw7tlTOXHHBoVdBrLl/7P0y371/dtL04zjEYYd9ZVvG/vwuKTG9@dF9UzmUm07lk0PfOm2muxqFfxQh48AA/MYfN3CDoI/HeDU1e0ZFnAEsgYtGsxwjSUr9akVGQa9B2J474CIWZGdiWQRWRIZY1oCHbqEHeYC4x5rxdrc6mXIVP8rR3d0csyxuE0R9YTxYYWUGbktcIM2n8T8VOuSMNK3@T4b8YiGP/@UPAXZKXJ0MjD2RDZHhk7GlH8yiTW64j@ZRHmHmbuMlf4arw) :)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts stdin for list, prints matrix to stdout.

Uses [Dennis's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165301/43319).

```apl
+\⍉↑⍴⍨¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L92zKPezkdtEx/1bnnUu@LQikd9U0ES/xXAoIDLSMdQx1jHkAvG1zFAMJFEjbkQGozgbGMdAyT1hjpGQKNMdEwRIgZA0w2AguY6FgA)

`⎕` stdin

`⍴⍨¨` **r**eshape-selfie of each

`↑` mix list of lists into matrix, filling with 0s

`⍉` transpose

`+\` cumulative row-wise sum

The `⍉` doesn't make any computational difference, so it could potentially be left out and `\` changed to `⍀` to sum column-wise instead of row-wise.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>88</s> 79 bytes

Returns `[]` for `[0]`.

```javascript
f=(a,y,b=a.map((_,x)=>a.map(c=>y>=c|x--<0?0:s+=c,s=0)|s))=>s?[b,...f(a,-~y)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDtTsMwDPzPU/RnItzMSVvYJtI9SBShLKwINJZpQWiVJl69OFtpBVGcj/Odz1be3ZeL/vR2/CwP4WU3DJ1mDnrYaic@3JGxZzhz3d6A123fan85l@UTbnAd77WHqJFfIidR3JgtCCE6cii/e27Xxg4@HGLY78Q@vLKOGbScF4tFYWwRToUx1t79U8hfBb0ysprIysK4M5ECNckU1CRKZ@4FCDj7Aa3k9@fOpwNFRA3NPCXhB5AIsqEyJL6BFcj6CpDIR5BqBEiVq@mN5JI3IKOxbDn3oKS8Rg2KRkgeKXeLChS1Xdr093b4AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

```python
lambda x:[[sum(n*(n>j)for n in x[:i+1])for i in range(len(x))]for j in range(max(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDsIgEEX3noJdQWdBqUbTpF6EssDYKk2ZNi0meHpk2Lj4mTcvM3/9hveCKo1dn2brH0/LYqv1/vEcjxzvkxiXjSFzyKJu3ak2RTgSm8XXwOcBeRTCkJ7@2ttYdArDHvZOawU1NFAb0DKHZpOjQBGBhGJB5ZszXIhlfpB5vcLNmAPVB6ovfe26OQwsQNVjBSMPolD6AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 64 bytes

```matlab
@(x,k=a=0*(x+(1:max(x))'))eval"for i=x;a(1:i,++k:end)+=i;end,a";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY1hS8MwEIa/91eEwTCxZ7lkretWIv6PkA@htlBWNxAdBfG31zeztggDRy7Jvc/de3eq38O5GVubZdn4LAc62GD5Xg6p1PvXMMhBqTulmnPoV@3pTXR2qAJKHaXpYd8cX1Rquwo/hVU11sKKT8ee1uLhSTgv4HDO@8TpX4YMcjNLZNMFNmTmgqEcOL6xn5h48RBO9Pz54xYySHMqlm3Qj6SZNJhj1Avakc4vglHckjaTYDh3c86YEkfCOjWWy1RAfYmcDJZGV2Q/sSGDReW/DLElU9zM1jc0IsorjK8yn3xVSd30fftxlC3VavwG)

#### Explanation:

Yet again: Expressions in the argument list and eval are used in one function :)

This takes `x` as input, and creates two identical matrices filled with zeros, with the dimensions `k=a=zeros(length(x),max(x))`. This is achieved by adding the horizontal vector `x` with a vertical vector with `1:max(x)`, implicitly expanding the dimensions to a 2D-array, then multiplying this with zero. `~(x+...)` doesn't work unfortunately, since that forces `a` to be a logical array throughout the rest of the function.

`for i=x` is a loop that for each iteration makes `i=x(1)`, then `i=x(2)` and so on. `a(1:i,k++:end)` is the part of the matrix that should be updated for each iteration. `1:i` is a vector saying which rows should be updated. If `i=0`, then this will be an empty vector, thus nothing will be updated, otherwise it's `1, 2 ...`. `++k:end` increments the `k` matrix by one, and creates a range from the first value of this matrix (`1,2,3...`) and up to the last column of the `a` matrix. `+=i` adds the current value to `a`. `end,a` ends the loop and outputs `a`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Thread@Accumulate@PadRight[#~Table~#&/@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclNCsIwEIbhqwwEshrpj4pulHiDIt2VLMY0tYHGRUlXIb16nAaGD@Z5PYXZegrOUJ7gkft5tTSqlzGb3xYKVnU0vt13DoPYe/osdheyUkLL3K3uxwqnJ0yD0BokVApirBNCbI45H9MitOVBqPlKZEJguCBcC3BpSme8IdxTyn8)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>142</s> <s>135</s> 134 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,i=0,j,s,m=0;for(int q:a)m=q>m?q:m;int[][]r=new int[m][l];for(;i<m;i++)for(j=s=0;j<l;j++)r[i][j]=s+=i<a[j]?a[j]:0;return r;}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rZHRbsIgFIbvfYpz2UZKULdsEdHsAeaNuzO9OGvRlQFVoC7G9Nk7WucTrAmQA5zz8f8HhRfMVPndFRq9h3es7G0CUNkg3QELCdt@Oxzs830ORTJEgCmP522ccfiAoSpgCxYEdJitbzEJtECqpT2GL6KIJ0YwfqhdXw/nJaZGnNdmc14afkEHTlj5M7xi8r3Oh0xusmzNeNrHSvhYr1aaq@k0dX2WyoWfCrPCGG36Zcm4k6FxFhxvO37Xdmo@ddT2J/FSVyWYaDLZBVfZ4@Dk7nB39UEaWjeBnuJV0DZRsTm0CZWmb87h1dNSytNHfS9NLC2Sh@j8xto0HXryb9JsNNJiNNKczMdTRRgZsVtkThbkiTyP6HUWieP9woxFIIvIF/L6gLaTtvsF)

```java
a->{              // Method with integer-array parameter and integer-matrix return-type
  int l=a.length, //  Length of the input-array
      i,j,        //  Index integers
      s,          //  Sum integer
  m=0;for(int q:a)m=q>m?q:m;
                  //  Determine the maximum of the input-array
  var r=new int[m][l];
                  //  Result-matrix of size `m` by `l`
  for(;m-->0;)    //  Loop `i` over the rows
    for(j=s=0;    //   Reset the sum to 0
        j<l;j++)  //   Inner loop `j` over the columns
      r[m][j]=s+= //    Add the following to the sum `s`, add set it as current cell:
        m<a[j]?   //     If the row-index is smaller than the `j`'th value in the input:
         a[j]     //      Add the current item to the sum
        :         //     Else:
         0;       //      Leave the sum the same by adding 0
  return r;}      //  Return the result-matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 39 bytes

```
{.$):M;;{[.](*[0]M*+M<}%zip{{\.@+}*]}%}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlf979aT0XTytfaujpaL1ZDK9og1ldL29emVrUqs6C6OkbPQbtWK7ZWtfZ/XcL/aCMFQwVjBcNYAA)

Uses [Dennis's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165301/41024).

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```ruby
->a{(1..a.max).map{|n|w=0;a.map{|r|w+=(r<n)?0:r}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDsIwDET3fkXHVhyRk4JAQOBDrAxh6EZVRaoa1OTbg0OHO9@z7AvL@1tGW45Pv3VaKa8@PvZi85amtFq6@x1CWg@2C4@pf9Et5JwLs4HGAO3AJKpzEBmYmkD4b2Hk5oRzzSQPJHjB1bm9N6amnVuOGDk61@TyAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 60 bytes

```
a->matrix(vecmax(a),#a,i,j,vecsum([a[k]|k<-[1..j],a[k]>=i]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzRCsIwDEV/JcyXFtKxTkUfXH@k5CGIk25OSp0ywX@vaSFc7jkXEjkFc495hAEyG7fwmsKmPrfrwptijTvGgBOKeL0X5dnP9Jsvxtu2nQgLuiGQ1pljfHwVg3EQU3iuUpsCDYzyRyN435GkLbEv0SP0FRA6uTqKQhBxQDhWIYutu8gTwplI5z8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÔËÆD
z ®å+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1MvGRAp6IK7lKw&footer=V2ewSgpWaVfUIGMg%2bSDyV2wpbbgKUmlYaTFYPc7K5y0paVggcFggtw&input=WwpbMiwxLDMsMV0KWzBdClsxXQpbM10KWzIsMl0KWzMsMCwwXQpbMSwyLDMsNCw1XQpbMTAsMSwwLDMsNyw4XQpdLW1S) (includes all test cases)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
m∫T0m´R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/dRx@oQg9xDW4L@//8fbaRjqGOsYxgLAA)

Dennis' method.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 24 Bytes

```
{+\'+(x#'x),'(x-|/x)#'0}
```

Dennis algorithm

### Sample

```
  {+\'+(x#'x),'(x-|/x)#'0}2 1 3 1
(2 3 6 7;2 2 5 5;0 0 3 3)
```

numeric arrays in k are represented as a sequence of values without separators, so `2 1 3 1` is the same as `[2,1,3,1]` in other languages.

k Use the syntax `(..;..;..)` to represent an heterogeneous or multi-level list, so `(2 3 6 7;2 2 5 5;0 0 3 3)` is the same as `[[2,3,6,7],[2,2,5,5],[0,0,3,3]]` in other languages

### Explanation

- `{..x..}` defines an anobymous function with implicit arg x
- `+\array` is the cummulative sum of the elems of the array
- `f'matrix` applies f to each row ('=each) of the matrix preserving matrix shape, so `+\'matrix` calculates cummulative sum of the elems of each row of the matrix
- `n#x` signifies take n copies of x value. if n and x are
  both arryas of the same length, `n#'x` applies `#` to each pair, so
  `2 1 3 1#'2 1 3 1` is the same as `(2#2; 1#1; 3#3; 1#1)` and
  evaluates to `(2 2;,1;3 3 3;,1)`. NOTE one-item list is represented as `,item`
- `a,b` joins (catenates) arrays a and b. `a,'b` applies `,` to each corresponding items of a and b: if both are matrices of the same shape, catenates each corresponding pair of rows
- `|/array` applies binary operator `|` (max) over the elements of the array (reduce), so `|/2 1 3 1` is equivalent to `2|1|3|1` and reduces to 3
- `(x-|/x)` substract to each element of x the maximum of the array, so `2 1 3 1 - |/2 1 3 1` is the same as `2 1 3 1 - 3` and evaluate to `-1 -2 0 -2`
- `array#'0` is "take n copies of 0" for each value n in array. It really uses "abs(n) take 0", so we don't worry about sign. `-1 -2 0 -2#'0` evaluates to `(,0;0 0;();0 0)`. NOTE.- `()` is the empty array

k applies unary operators and binary operators right to left, and parenthesis indicate precedence. NOTE.- k uses one-letter symbols, with two meanings (unary op or binary op) depending of context (example `+` as binary op is sum, but as unary op is flip (transpose).

- `#'` is a binary op modified by `'` adverb. Its arguments are `(x-|/x)` and `0`.

  - Evaluates `x-|/x` first. `|` it's a binary op (max), but adverb `/` convert it to unary (max over x), and evaluates to `3`. The resulting `x-3` is a binary op (minus), with args `x`and `3`, and evals to `-1 -2 0 -2`
  - `-1 -2 0 -2#'0` evals to `(,0;0 0;();0 0)`
- The actual expr is `+\'+(x#'x),'(,0;0 0;();0 0)`. `,` is a binary op (join) modified by `'` adverb (each): we need to evaluate the left arg `(x#'x)`

  - `x#'x` is `2 1 3 1#'2 1 3 1`, and applies binay op `#` (take) to each pair. The result is `(2 2;,1;3 3 3;,1)`
  - `(2 2;,1;3 3 3;,1),'(,0;0 0;();0 0)` applies binary op `,` modified by (') each, and join each pair of corresponding values. The result is `(2 2 0;1 0 0;3 3 3;1 0 0)`
- `+` is a monad operator that transpose (flip) the matrix, so the result is `(2 1 3 1;2 0 3 0;0 0 3 0)`
- `+\'matrix` calculates cummulative sums of each row of the matrix, so eval to `(2 3 6 7;2 2 5 5;0 0 3 3)